# hash sum mismatch on apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux

I'm getting the dreaded hash sum mismatch error when running sudo apt-get update:

```
Failed to fetch http://ftp2.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz Hash Sum mismatch
```

What I've tried

- A lot of different mirrors
- Make my phone a wifi hotspot and run apt-get update. This just used a different mirror
- Removed everything in /var/lib/apt/lists and then run apt-get clean apt-get update again
- Changed server in sources.list to https
- run apt-key to refresh the key

In the end I downloaded the latest kali virtualbox image and still the same!

*edit*

Downloaded the latest virtualbox VM image and the same again...

Also, **maybe related** is that it seems I'm unable to clone some git repos anymore:

git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

> Cloning into 'rtl8812au'... remote: Enumerating objects: 116, done.
> remote: Counting objects: 100% (116/116), done. remote: Compressing
> objects: 100% (76/76), done. error: inflate: data stream error
> (incorrect data check)B/s    fatal: pack has bad object at offset
> 6162461: inflate returned -3 fatal: index-pack failed

Is there anything else to check for?

Comment: Related:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593629/sudo-apt-get-update-hash-sum-mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kali needs only one line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` if necessary with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Comment out all other lines in sources.list by preceding them with a `#` character and save the file.

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Run the following commands to remove the `hash sum mismatch` error.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  
sudo apt update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz  
sudo apt clean  
sudo apt update
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, this compression story doesn't repair the hash check problem

Comment: I talk about compression, not about how sources.list is composed

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Maybe ask about it on Ask Ubuntu. You're also a user there.